# Wrote the whole game in one class MyGdxGame. How do i mae the main menu? libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a big problem.I wrote the whole game in same(one) class MyGdxGame extends from the ApplicationAdapter. How do I make the main menu? So that when opening the game, the main menu opens, in which 1 button, when pressed, opens the game itself (MyGdxGame)? Just tell me how to do it (what to create, what to change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's better to achieve high cohesion but when you code inside one class, cohesiveness become very low.**

Use `Screen` and `Game` class to implement more than one screen as in your case like `MainScreen`, `GameScreen`, `LevelScreen`...

But if you don't want to implement that use flags for different screen in your  `MyGdxGame` class.

```
public enum GameScreen{
    MENU_SCREEN, GAME_SCREEN, LEVELSCREEN;
}
```

In `render` method of your `MyGdxGame`

```
public GameScreen currentScreen=GameScreen.MENU_SCREEN;

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(currentScreen==GameScreen.MENU_SCREEN){

        //render objects for Menu Screen

    }else if(currentScreen==GameScreen.GAME_SCREEN){

        //render objects for Game Screen
    }
}
```

Change value of `currentScreen` when you want to move on other screen.

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    if(currentScreen==GameScreen.MENU_SCREEN){

        //detect button of MenuScreen by bounds or any other way
        if(check in bound){
            currentScreen==GameScreen.GAME_SCREEN;
        }

    }else if(currentScreen==GameScreen.GAME_SCREEN){

        // for Game Screen
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

Pelocho suggested to use abstract method inside enum.

```
public enum GameScreen{
        MENU_SCREEN{

            @Override
            public void render(MyGdxGame gdxGame) {

            }
        }, GAME_SCREEN{

            @Override
            public void render(MyGdxGame gdxGame) {

            }

        }, LEVELSCREEN{

            @Override
            public void render(MyGdxGame gdxGame) {

            }
        };

        public abstract void render(MyGdxGame gdxGame);
    }
```

And inside `render` method of `MyGdxGame`

```
@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    currentScreen.render(this);
}
```

Comment: What about having an abstract `render` method in the `GameScreen` enum and calling `currentScreen.render()` inside the `MyGdxGame.render()` method? You simplify the method and make sure that every screen have a render implementation

Comment: i have a static non-static problem: `GAME_SCREEN{

   @Override
   public void render(MyGdxGame gdxGame) {
    field();
    if (count > 6) {
     checker();
    }
    drawoutline();
   }

  }` Error: Non-static method 'checker()' cannot be referenced from a static contex. What i should do? I need all variables and methods set to static?

Comment: In `render` method  of enum there is an argument `gdxGame` of type `MyGdxGame`, you can use that variable like `gdxGame.field()`

Comment: ok, i have another one problem: when screen changing method create on GameScreen isnt activating.  Why?

Comment: how you change `Screen` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it properly instead of hacking a menu in. If you look at the [Screen](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html) class it has the about the same methods as the ApplicationAdapter (show, render, resize, dispose, hide, pause, resume). If you would create a new class and have it implement `Screen` you can start to cut/paste from your main class to this screen class. If you have something in the `Create` method then either put it in the `Show` method or in the constructor. You then create another `Screen` for your main menu, options, credits, etc.

Have you main class `MyGdxGame` extend from `Game` instead of `ApplicationAdapter` delete all methods except the `create` method. In the create method you can load your assets and call your first screen like this `setScreen(new MenuScreen())`. For changing screens you have several options.

- Pass the Game object allong with the screens so you can do `game.setScreen(..)`
- Have some sort of screen manager with `public static` methods to change screens.
- `Gdx.app.getApplicationListener` can be casted into game. This way you can change screen from anywhere in your LibGDX app. `((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener).setScreen(myScreen)`

If you are feeling scared you will destroy functionality, make a backup of you game in its current state. Abstracting code from big classes to new smaller classes is a important task for each programmer so it will be good practice. If you feel at any point that a certain piece of code should belong to another/new class feel free to do so. There are many ways to do things and keeping your code readable and understandable is your number 1 priority.